# PHP - Looping Through rows in MySql and displaying a field based on user's click

Tags: php, html

My first question on Stack Overflow, so please forgive if I make any mistake.

I have a database, in which I store the User Id and the title and corresponding content. Then in a PHP page, I loop through the rows of the table and display the title of the content in an anchor tag.

The problem is, When the user clicks on a specific title, he should be redirected to new page where the content corresponding to the title which he clicked is displayed.

Could you please guide me as to how to achieve it?

Thanks.

Here is the code that I've tried.

```
<?php
        $counter1 = 0;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM blogdata2";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<a style='color: #E64A19;' href='#'/>".$arrayContent[$counter1]['title'];
        echo "<br/>";
        $counter1++;
```

Comment: You can print the PRIMARY id of the rows in the anchor tag and retrieve the row using that id from the new page

Comment: I quite understood what you said. But could you please explain how to retrieve the unique row id in a new page. I am sorry, i am new to all this, so please bear with me.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try like this...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blogdata2";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<a style='color: #E64A19;' href='newpage.php?content=".$row['content']."'>".$row['title']."</a>";
        echo "<br/>";
    }
```

and in `newpage.php`

```
<?php 
 $content=$_GET['content'];
 echo "<p>".$content."</p">;
```

But following way is best...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blogdata2";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<a style='color: #E64A19;' href='newpage.php?id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['title']."</a>";
        echo "<br/>";
    }
```

and in newpage.php

```
<?php

$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM blogdata2 WHERE id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo "<p>".$row['content']."</p>";
```

Comment: ever heard of sql injection?

Comment: @Your Common Sense yes sir..he must use prepared statements for this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It does work. But I have encountered another problem, regarding its working. Whenever I click the title, it surely shows the content corresponding to the title. But, whenever there is a special character like  ' , the text after this special character is not displayed.

Comment: Prepared statements is indeed the best, far from your posted code. You could have at least add a mysqli_real_escape_string... Sanjay do not use the posted code as described, if you do so, please add after the variable $id something like : $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($id); then replace in the SQL request $id by $value

Comment: like this `$id=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['id']);`

Comment: @ Anyone_ph you are wrong...dont teach me $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($id);  see there `mysqli()` so you need $con variable..kid joking

Comment: @ Anyone_ph why you voted down..he is beginner. if  you have best idea post your answer.

Comment: As I said (and do in my code) prepared statement should be use instead of the old way, using mysqli. You rushed your answer without thinking one second that the code you provided to him was badly wrong, leading to one of the worth security hole and, the first thing that every beginner in PHP know => the SQL injection.

Comment: haha after how much time you heard about `SQL injection` of your beginning time in php.`DON"T EAT MORE AT A TIME>>` .